# PowerShell and bat file logging

Tags: powershell, batch-file, logging

I wrote a simple script in PowerShell:

```
############### script #############################
$Database = @("DatabaseNo1","DatabaseNo2","DatabaseNo3")

Write-Host Running on $Database[0]
#sqlcmd ...........
Write-Host Running on $Database[1]
#sqlcmd ...........
Write-Host Running on $Database[2]
#sqlcmd ...........
Write-Host Stopping...
#psexec ........
#############################################
```

This script runs with sqlcmd and psexec and copy commands.
I need to log PowerShell script activity. 
Then I wrote bat file which run PowerShell script

```
#############################################################
del d:\scripts\log.log
powershell -file d:\scripts\script.ps1 >> d:\scripts\log.log
#############################################################
```

I have a problem with formatting the log file.
This file looks like:

Running on DatabaseNo1Running on DatabaseNo2Running on DatabaseNo3Stoping...

And I want this log to look like:

Running on DatabaseNo1

some data from sqlcmd

Running on DatabaseNo2

some data from sqlcmd

Running on DatabaseNo3

some data from sqlcmd

Stopping...

Some psexec data

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use `write-host`. Basically its intended usage is for writing to the console.

I'd use `write-output` or `write-verbose`, these two cmdlets will pass the output to the pipeline, or in your case when using redirection towards a file:

```
$Database = @("DatabaseNo1","DatabaseNo2","DatabaseNo3")
Write-Output "Running on $($Database[0])"
#sqlcmd ...........
Write-Output "Running on $($Database[1])"
#sqlcmd ...........
Write-Output "Running on $($Database[2])"
#sqlcmd ...........
Write-Output Stopping...
#psexec ........
#############################################
```

Here is the output when the following command is executed:

`powershell -file d:\scripts\test.ps1 >> d:\scripts\log.log`

```
Running on DatabaseNo1
Running on DatabaseNo2
Running on DatabaseNo3
Stopping...
```